# How to make key words of code highlight on SO

Tags: discussion

How to make key words of code highlight on SO? When I choose `C` tags, it does. But sometimes the code is not C.

Comment: Read [ask]. There is url to formatting where you can read how to define what syntax highlighting you want to chose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the help for formatting Options: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help